# What does "It is on sale" mean?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

I was looking though a list of ready-phrases for a shopping situation and encountered this one:

> It is on sale.

What does it mean?

Comment: Have you looked up [sale](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sale) in a dictionary? What did you find confusing about the definitions there?

Comment: @oerkelens In some sources I find that it's just a synonim to "for sale". In other sources it is a synonym to "at a discounted price". So I wanna know for sure.

Comment: It can mean either - but the usual meaning is that it is for sale at a reduced price. To be sure, you need _context_.

Comment: @oerkelens Great explanation. Why not convert it to an answer?

Comment: Because it is more or less how dictionary definitions work... if a word (or expression) has several meanings, the correct meaning has to be provided by context.

Comment: @oerkelens Didn't find "on sale" in dictionary!

Comment: I provided a link in my first comment... and that was, I think, the first link that Google gave me for _define sale_. _On sale_, with both meanings, is given in that source :)

Comment: @oerkelens Yep, I get it. Most likely I was searching for "to be on sale" and didn't find any reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the item is offered at a reduced or discounted price for a limited period.

Contrast "for sale", which merely means the item is available for purchase.